# How to correctly add images in Processing for android

Tags: android, image, processing, android-image

Recently I have started to work on a processing game that I want to try on android, the only problem is that I started in java mode and switched to android later, so now whenever I call an image it would give me an error. I added dataPath("") but that only gave me another error, I am not very well familiarized with the android mode so any help would be greatly appreciated! Here is my code for declaring images below.

```
void setup(){
  size(1080,1080);
  background(r1,g1,b1);
  heart1 = loadImage(dataPath("")+"heart-UP.png");

  heart2 = loadImage(dataPath("")+"heart-UP.png");
  heart3 = loadImage(dataPath("")+"heart-UP.png");
  restart = loadImage("Restart-UP(1).png");

  mute = loadImage(dataPath("")+"mute-OFF.png");
  music = new SoundFile(this, "4RunSong.wav");

  restart.resize(540,270);

  music.loop();
}
```

Also, the error I kept on getting after I added dataPath("") was:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File /data/user/0/processing.test.ranjan_4run/filesheart-UP.png contains a path separator

Comment: Same here @Z3R0 , did you end up finding a solution for this?

Comment: I have not used this project in a year, so I cannot give a good answer @erickva but I think I got rid of dataPath(""), I have lost my knowledge of Processing so I am unable to shed light on this further